# Java save mp3 file

Tags: java

I am trying to create import images and mp3 files from one directory using a file chooser and save them to another . The images went fine but I cant seem to find out how to save the mp3 file .

**Images**

```
@Override
 public void saveFile(File file) {
  //Get image path
  String imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  String imageName = file.getName();
  System.out.println(imagePath);

  //Read image
  try {
   bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
   System.out.println("Reading complete.");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }

  //write image
  try {
   f = new File("H:\\TestFolder\\images\\" + imageName); //output file path
   ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", f);
   System.out.println("Writing complete.");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }
 }
```

**Mp3**

```
@Override
public void saveFile(File file) {

    try{
        f = new File(file, "H:\\TestFolder\\test.mp3"); //file.getAbsolutePath();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
File f = new File("H:\\TestFolder\\test.mp3");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("H:\\TestFolder2\\blabla.mp3"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int len;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
outstream.close();
```